# Unable to run selenium WebDriver JavaScript bindings

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver

I'm currently using the selenium binding for python and would like to evaluate the JavaScript binding but am stuck with the sample application!
As I cannot seem to understand, what's wrong in this example, any help would be appreciated.

my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "selenium_tests",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^1.21.4",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.43.5"
  }
}
```

my script looks like this:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
    build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function () {
    'use strict';
    return driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
    });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

and the error stack when running it is as follows:

```
D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1745
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Wait timed out after 1039ms
    at D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1412:29
    at D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:444:12)
    at then (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:497:7)
    at Object.webdriver.promise.asap (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:749:11)
    at newFrame.then.e (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1656:25)
    at D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
    at notify (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:444:12)
==== async task ====
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.wait (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1397:15)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.wait (D:\selenium_node\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:589:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\selenium_node\original_sample.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the friendly people supporting selenium, I solved the mystery and I'm just plain stupid.
Because www.google.com gets automatically redirected depending on where your ip address is located, I've landed on a localized google page and the title was no longer 'webdriver - Google Search'.

Just using the proper localized title or prevent google not to localize using

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
```

solved the problem.